# How to prove this inequality for non-negative finite set function

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

If $\mu$ be a non-negative finite set function on the field $\mathcal F$, then

1. $\mu(\cup_{i=1}^nA_i)\leq\Sigma_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)$, for $A_1,A_2,...,A_n\in\mathcal F$.
2. $\mu(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)\geq\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty\mu(A_i)$, for $A_1,A_2,...\in\mathcal F$ and $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in\mathcal F$.

I don't know where to start because I have not been told whether $\mu$ is finitely additive or $\sigma$-additive or neither?

Could you please give me a hint on how to start?

Comment: @podiki, but that is only helpful if I know $\mu$ is finitely additive or sigma additive.

Comment: Yes I missed that originally and so I deleted my comment.

Comment: Those two claims are false in general. For example, if $0 < \mu(\emptyset) < \infty$, then 2 is violated.

Comment: @Mason, what if $\mu$ is finitely additive?

Comment: @user3741635 Then $1$ is true. $2$ is false if any set has positive $\mu(A)$ since you can take $A_i = A$.